# Haskell: test if list length < 4

Tags: haskell

I have the following haskell function that returns `Nothing` if the `String` is shorter than 4 characters:

```
  stringToMove :: String -> Maybe Move
  stringToMove [] = Nothing
  stringToMove [a] = Nothing
  stringToMove [a, b] = Nothing
  stringToMove [a, b, c] = Nothing
  stringToMove (l1:n1:l2:n2:rest) = Just (stringToCoords l1 n1, stringToCoords l2 n2)
```

I could test on `length string`, but as far as I read, this is not the haskell way of writing this, since if `String` is long, all of it will be evaluated.

Is there an elegant way of writing this without having to repeat `Nothing` in each line?

Comment: If you *only* want the check -- and don't care about the bindings -- there is also `null . drop 3`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  stringToMove :: String -> Maybe Move
  stringToMove (l1:n1:l2:n2:rest) = Just (stringToCoords l1 n1, stringToCoords l2 n2)
  stringToMove _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

I just feel like chiming in, if you have a lot of checks like this and you want to return a `Maybe`, you can use `do` notation:

```
stringToMove :: String -> Maybe Move
stringToMove s = do
    l1:n1:l2:n2:_ <- return s
    return (stringToCoords l1 n1, stringToCoords l2 n2)
```

You can do failable bindings as many times as you like, and if any of them fails, the function will return `Nothing`.

Comment: Your solution is awesome, I'm going to use it, but I have to accept the other answer since this is the way to go in the general case

Comment: I really dislike the implicit use of `fail` here in an intentionally-inexhaustive pattern match. The `foo <- return bar` *looks* like it is redundant and should be replaced with a `let`, but actually there is error checking hidden in there.

Comment: @amalloy well, that's what's clever about this answer, isn't it? But I agree that it would probably be clearer to write explicit `<- Just s` instead of `<- return s`. To still stay polymorphic, `<- pure s` would also be an option – it's completely equivalent to `return`, but hints that there's _not_ a forgotten monad-law reduction here.